# Jquery Disable div and disable click on it

Tags: jquery, click

I am trying to disable click event and disable div once I click on the item. I am unable to achieve this functionality. Any help?
[What I have tried](http://jsfiddle.net/yE69a/)

```
<div class="ordrClone">
                       Image 1
                    </div>
<div class="ordrClone">
                       Image 2
                    </div>
<div class="ordrClone">
                       Image 3
                    </div>

<div>
   <input type="button" id= "btnCancel" value="Enable"> 
</div>

 $('.ordrClone').click(function () {
        $('.ordrClone').not(this).each(function() {
            $(this).off('click');
        });
    });

$('#btnCancel').click(function () {
     $('.ordrClone').each(function() {
            $(this).on('click');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this)` instead of this:

```
$('.ordrClone').not($(this)).each(function() {
```

And also create a callback function and use that callback on the on method:

$(this).on('click');//it's wrong way to do.

```
$(this).on('click',callback);
```

see [on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more detail

But if you want to use the function only for once you can use the [one method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of on method.

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution is

```
$(document).on('click', '.ordrClone:not(.disabled)', function () {
    console.log('clicked')
    $('.ordrClone').not(this).addClass('disabled');
});

$('#btnCancel').click(function () {
    $('.ordrClone').removeClass('disabled');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4zkCS/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one) instead of [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) like,

```
$('.ordrClone').one('click',function () {
      // your code worked once
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yE69a/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [One](http://api.jquery.com/one/), if you want to click once only

```
$(document).one('.ordrClone','click',function () {
        $('.ordrClone').not(this).each(function() {
            $(this).off('click');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**$("#btnCancel").click(function() { $(this).unbind('click'); }**

This should unbind the 'click' functionality of the item you just clicked.  You can disable an element many different ways.  A really popular way is .hide()`ing the code and using it when needed, but the above code should work fine to disable a specific event from a form element.